# FFMPEG video rendering on raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm currently planning on making a little GIF making machine.
After a button press, the rPi records a 5 seconde video from a 720p USB camera.
Then, the rPi should chroma key the video and then convert it into a GIF.

Sadly, I don't have the FFMPEG comand yet.

Do you think, that the rPi 3b+ has enough power to render those videos?
It would need to be done in less than 30 seconds.

All while displaying the image of the camera.

Comment: it could be - have  you tried?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, as I haven't got the FFMPEG command yet and as I am new to FFMPEG and handling video on rPi, I really want to check if it is possible at all, before investing days of testing

Comment: how will you check if ffmpeg does what *you* want if you don't have ffmpeg? Of course, you could be lucky and somebody has already done what you want to do, but what are the chances that they'd read your question? - I would say, based on things that I've done with ffmpeg, that the pi is powerful enough to render a 5 second GIF in 30 seconds - and also, it takes 30 seconds to install ffmpeg, and would take about 10 minutes to determine if it does what you want

Comment: I know that FFMPEG can do it, as I have done some research allready. I also found a command that will do all necessary things, but haven't tried it so I don't share it yet.